# Hartshorne, Exercise III 4.2 (a): A morphism $\mathcal{O}^r \to f_* \mathscr{M}$ that is an iso over the generic point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, pushforward

I'm having some trouble with Exercise III 4.2 a) in Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*. It is

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a finite surjective morphism of integral noetherian schemes. Show that there is a coherent sheaf $\mathscr{M}$ on $X$, and a morphism of sheaves $\alpha: \mathcal{O}^r_Y \to f_* \mathscr{M}$ for some $r > 0$, such that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism at the generic point.

I solved the affine case: If $Y = \text{Spec } A$, then $X = \text{Spec }B$ and $f$ comes from a homomorphism of integral domains $A \to B$, where $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra. This means there is a surjection $A^n \to B$ of $A$-modules. Localizing is exact, so at the generic point this is still a surjection $Q(A)^n \to B_{(0)}$. But $Q(A)$ is a field, so we can choose a basis $Q(A)^r \subset Q(A)^n$, which gives an isomorphism $Q(A)^r \to B_{(0)}$. The corresponding map $A^r \to B$ is the desired morphism.

So the "obvious" generalization would be to take the structure sheaf  $\mathscr{M} = \mathcal{O}_X$. But this cannot work, as the following counterexample illustrates:

Consider $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$, defined by $[x:y] \mapsto [x^2:y^2]$. Giving a morphism $\alpha: \mathcal{O}_Y^r \to f_* \mathscr{M}$ is the same as choosing $r$ elements from $\Gamma(X, \mathscr{M})$. But $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = k$, so we can only choose $k$-linearly dependent elements. No morphism $\mathcal{O}_Y^r \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ can give an isomorphism at the generic point $\eta$, because $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_\eta \cong \mathcal{O}_{Y,\eta}^2$, and the image of $\mathcal{O}_Y^r \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X $ will only be $1$-dimensional at $\eta$.

I'm a bit clueless at this point. Maybe one has to glue the affine case together and yields an invertible sheaf $\mathscr{M}$? But I don't think that replacing $\mathcal{O}_X$ by $\mathcal{O}_X(d)$ really changes anything in the example. How to proceed here?

Comment: could you kindly clarify your argument "But $\Gamma$..."? If you take $P^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ and take $F_1=O$, $F_2=O(1)$, then we have a morphism $F_1^{\oplus 2}\rightarrow F_2$ which is surjective on global sections.

Comment: also, can't you just run the following argument? $f$ is affine, so we can pick an affine open neighbourhood of the generic point of $Y$ (which is a Noetherian integral domain), its inverse image is also an affine open. Stalks can be evaluated on non-empty open sets, so your reasoning for affine case does the job.

Comment: First the example: Note that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\eta}$ is a field extension of $k$: The global sections $s_1,\dots,s_r \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = k$  determined by $\alpha$ will always be $k$-linearly dependent. This does not change if we localize at the generic point, so the restrictions of the sections can not generate $(f_* \mathcal{O}_X)_\eta$, which is two dimensional as a $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\eta}$-vector space.

Comment: well, maybe I am wrong. Have a look here (https://math.berkeley.edu/~ceur/notes_pdf/Eur_HartshorneNotes.pdf). There is a solution to this exercise.

Comment: They claim that $\mathcal{O}_U$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$ for $U \subset X$ open affine  ( they probably mean the push-forward $i_* \mathcal{O}_U$ where $i: U \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion). I think this is not true. In general, if $A$ is a ring and $f \in A$, then the localization $A_f$ is *not* a finitely generated $A$-module, and so for $U = \text{Spec } A_f \hookrightarrow X = \text{Spec} A$, the sheaf $i_*\mathcal{O}_U \in \text{Mod}(X)$ is not coherent.

Comment: I think that it does not matter that much whether you consider the pushforward of the structure sheaf from an open subset or the structure sheaf itself (the stalks should be the same, right?).

Comment: Yeah, but it is not a coherent sheaf, only quasi-coherent. Also, the stalks of points not in $U$ might differ.

Comment: I was made aware of this post by an email.  I should admit that what I wrote in the document that @schematic_boi pointed to is not a correct solution (sorry...).  As the author suggests, one needs to do a some gluing.  I may post a correct solution here if I find a time to do so and no one has posted anything by then... (again, sorry... was learning these stuff at the time, not that I'm much better now...)

Comment: @red_trumpet I am sorry for my stupid remarks, now I see you were right all along. The situation is slightly confusing in that the stalks are actually isomorphic, and this isomorphism is induced by a map of quasi-coherent sheaves, but there does not appear to be a good map of coherent sheaves (as you have undoubtedly noticed).

Comment: I have reached a somewhat disturbing conclusion. Some googling (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432718/structure-of-coherent-sheaf-over-bbb-p1?rq=1) convinced me that a coherent sheaf on $P^1$ is a direct sum of a locally free sheaf and a torsion sheaf (i.e. supported at a finite number of closed points, in our case). Coherent locally free sheaves on $P^1$ are direct sums of locally free sheaves of rank 1 (depending on your preference, that's Birkhoff or Grothendieck or whatever).

Comment: The torsion summand should not matter because it does not contribute to the generic stalk. Your argument applies to locally free sheaves of rank 1, and by splitting, to all coherent locally free sheaves. If somebody could set me straight, that would be great.

Comment: @schematic_boi I did the calculation in the $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ example and I think it actually works out. See my answer for this.

Comment: I think dhy on MO has solved this problem: https://mathoverflow.net/q/329828/138661

Comment: Thanks! I've not yet read this rigorously, but does he just take $\mathscr{M}$ to be the coherent subsheaf of $i_* \mathcal{O}_U$, which is generated by the global sections selected on the affine?

Comment: @red_trumpet the argument is of the form "a coherent sheaf exists because categorical blah blah". I am not entirely confident that you can choose an explicit coherent sheaf in general case. The comments by Piotr Achinger below the question might give something fairly explicit in the case we have lots of Cartier divisors (e.g. a factorial scheme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my answer on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/330923/111897):

Suppose we can solve the problem for affine schemes, and choose an open affine $j: V \hookrightarrow Y$ and let $i: U \hookrightarrow X$ be its preimage. Suppose we have a morphism
$$ \alpha_V:  \mathcal{O}_V^n \to (f|_U)_*\mathcal{O}_U$$
which is an isomorphism at the generic point $\eta$ of $Y$.

The problem is that $i_* \mathcal{O}$ is not in general coherent on $X$. But $\alpha_V$ chooses $n$ global sections $s_1,\dotsc,s_n \in \Gamma(X, i_* \mathcal{O}_U) = \Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_U)$, which can be used to define a morphism $\alpha_X: \mathcal{O}_X^n \to i_* \mathcal{O}_U$. Let $\mathscr{G}$ be the image of this morphism. Then $\mathscr{G}$ is coherent, because for every open affine $\text{Spec }A = W \subset X$, $\mathscr{G}(W) \subset (i_*\mathcal{O}_U)(W)$ is the $A$-submodule generated by $s_1|_W,\dotsc,s_n|_W$.

This allows us to define the morphism
$$ \alpha_Y: \mathcal{O}_Y^n \to f_* \mathscr{G} \subset (f i)_* \mathcal{O}_U$$
by takting the same global sections $s_1,\dots,s_n \in \Gamma(Y, f_* \mathscr{G})$. At the generic point this yields
$$
\mathcal{O}^n_{Y, \eta} \xrightarrow{\alpha_{Y, \eta}} (f_*\mathscr{G})_\eta \hookrightarrow ((fi)_* \mathcal{O}_U)_\eta,
$$
and the composition is $\alpha_{U, \eta}$ which is an isomorphism. Hence $\alpha_{Y, \eta}$ is an isomorphism as well.

---

This is not a full answer, I just think that in the example $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1, [x_0:x_1] \mapsto [x_0^2:x_1^2]$ the morphism $\alpha: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^2 \to f_*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$, which chooses the two generators of $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(1))$ *does* in fact work:

To differentiate the two instances of $\mathbb{P}^1$, let $x_0, x_1$ be the coordinates on the domain $X$ of $f$, and let $y_0, y_1$ be the coordinates on the image $Y = \mathbb{P}^1$. Then $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(1)) = \langle x_0, x_1 \rangle_k$, and $\alpha: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^2 \to f_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ is defined on global sections by sending the generator $e_i$ to $x_i$.

Choosing $U = D_+(y_1) \subset Y$, a principle open affine, we have $V = f^{-1}(U) = D_+(x_1)$. We want to study $\alpha$ restricted to $U$. Thus $U = \text{Spec } k\left[\frac{y_0}{y_1}\right]$, and $V = \text{Spec } k\left[\frac{x_0}{x_1}\right]$. The homomorphism of rings determining $f: V \to U$ is given by
$$ \frac{y_0}{y_1} \mapsto \left(\frac{x_0}{x_1}\right)^2.$$
The restriction $\langle x_0, x_1 \rangle_k = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(1)) \to \Gamma(V, \mathcal{O}(1)|_V) = k\left[\frac{x_0}{x_1}\right]$ is given by mapping $x_0 \mapsto \frac{x_0}{x_1}$, and $x_1 \mapsto 1$.

If we consider $k\left[\frac{x_0}{x_1}\right]$ as a $k\left[\frac{y_0}{y_1}\right]$-module we see that it has two generators, namely $1$ and $\frac{x_0}{x_1}$. This is because with the $k\left[\frac{y_0}{y_1}\right]$-action we only hit the even degrees (or odd degrees, depending where you start).

Both generators are hit by $\alpha|_U$, which is therefor surjective on $U$-sections (I think it even is an isomorphism).

Comment: Some additional info: if you take a degree $n$ self-map for $P^1$, then $f_*O(n-1)=O(n-1)^{\oplus r}$ for some $r$ I am too lazy to compute. Shown here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/329812/138661

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do the last part of this problem. I've gotten to the point where I have a map $f_*\mathcal{M}\to \mathcal{F}^r$ of coherent sheaves which is an isomorphism at the generic point and the former has vanishing higher cohomology groups. I want to conclude that $\mathcal{F}^r$ has vanishing cohomology groups but don't know how to do this.